# Method Calls Not Working

Tags: java, oop

The method calls at the end of the main method are giving me an error saying "non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context" I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong in the method call.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) 
 { 
   ArrayList<Candidate> voteCount = new ArrayList<Candidate>();
   //add objects to voteCount

   printListResults(voteCount);
   totalListVotes(voteCount);
   printListTable(voteCount);
}
 public void printListResults(ArrayList<Candidate> election) 
{ 
    //some code
}
public int totalListVotes(ArrayList<Candidate> election) 
{ 
    //some code
}
public void printListTable(ArrayList<Candidate> election) 
{ 

        //some code
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to declare these methods as static

```
public static void printListResults(ArrayList<Candidate> election) { 
    //some code
}
public static int totalListVotes(ArrayList<Candidate> election) { 
    //some code
}
public static void printListTable(ArrayList<Candidate> election) { 
    //some code
}
```

An alternative approach would be to instantiate an object of your class, as pointed out in the answer from JoschJava.  Either way will work.  Which approach you choose is partly a matter of taste and partly depends upon the needs of your application (which is beyond the scope of this question).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're trying to call a class method from a static method. You need to instantiate your class:

```
YourClass classObj = new YourClass();
classObj.printListResults(voteCount);
```

Comment: Why would these be class methods instead of just instance methods?

Comment: Sorry, I was typing too fast, of course your code contains the instance methods. EJK pointed everything out that you need to know.